# Why is this variable undeclared but still working?

Tags: ruby, variables

I'm a beginner & just started to learn ruby through Codecademy. I understand this will be a very simple question. Why are we declaring `answer2` in this code? Wouldn't they both be equal?

```
print "This is my question?"
answer = gets.chomp
answer2 = answer.capitalize 
answer.capitalize!
```

Thanks.

Comment: You will need to rewrite your question so it is more clear what you are asking for. :)

Comment: The question in the title doesn't seem to be the same as the question in the body…

Comment: The code is just a vaguely-connected example sequence, and neither of the variables appear to be used in any output. If you run it, you see the question then can type something, and that's it. Unless the codeacademy sample continues with more, then I think it is just showing some typical String manipulations and you should not read any functional purpose into it.

Answer (score 1):

They're trying to teach you the difference between `capitalize` and `capitalize!`. The first doesn't modify the string but rather returns a modified copy of it. While the latter (with a bang `!` mark) modifies the string itself.

So to further explain the example above, consider the following:

```
print "This is my question?"
answer = gets.chomp
answer2 = answer.capitalize
puts "answer= " + answer + ", while answer2= " + answer2
answer.capitalize!
puts "now answer= " + answer
```

So if we execute the previous code and enter `foobar` when it prompts, the output will be:

```
This is my question?foobar
answer= foobar, while answer2= Foobar
now answer= Foobar
```

Generally, methods in ruby don't modify the objects that called them, but rather return a modified copy. So in `some_object.some_method`, the `some_method` method is not going to change `some_object` but will return a copy of it with some modifications. Alternatively, methods with at bang `!` mark change the objects that called them. So `some_object.some_method!` will change `some_object` itself.